# Solve linear equations starting from approximate solution

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, linear-equation

In a problem I'm working on, there is a need to solve Ax=b where A is a n x n square matrix (typically n = a few thousand), and b and x are vectors of size n.  The trick is, it is necessary to do this many (billions) of times, where A and b change only very slightly in between successive calculations.

Is there a way to reuse an existing approximate solution for x (or perhaps inverse of A) from the previous calculation instead of solving the equations from scratch?

I'd also be interested in a way to get x to within some (defined) accuracy (eg error in any element of x < maxerr, or norm(error in x) < maxerr), rather than an exact solution (again, reusing the previous calculations).

Comment: Is there any property of your matrix A that you can share with us, e.g. what are the eigen values like, or how it is constructed?

Comment: @Bob It is symmetrical, real valued, all the values are c_ij/r_ij (c in a small range eg 1-2, r>some rmin>0)and all the changes are small changes in the r’s

Comment: for big matrices the matrix inverse is worth calculate by GEM ... so I think you could create a dependence list for reach row of matrix while GEM is computed and then on matrix change recompute only the rows that are dependent on changed row and leave the rest as is ... if the matrix is NxN this require N^2 bits of storage where N is few thousand it should be not a big problem... However this is just my intuition and have not done such thing yet so I might be wrong or in need of additional tweaking... using determinant approach is slow on big matrices but there the dependence is much clearer

Comment: so reusing already computed one is real possibility however the speed of computing is very low in comparison to GEM so it might not get you a speedup at all

Answer (score 3):

If the individual problems can be solved by the conjugate gradient method (i.e., A is symmetric, positive-definite, and real), then I would suggest

- Before the first time you solve for x, and at intervals of Θ(n) times thereafter, compute the Cholesky decomposition of A.
- Use the Cholesky decomposition for the preconditioned conjugate gradient method.

The idea is: with a dense matrix, the asymptotic cost of Θ(1) steps of preconditioned conjugate gradient is Θ(n²), and the asymptotic cost of Cholesky is Θ(n³), so every Θ(n) solutions for x costs Θ(n³). If we used the exact A that we are trying to solve for as the preconditioner, then preconditioned conjugate gradient would converge in one step! The hope is that, however A is changing, it does so slowly enough that the preconditioning is effective enough for constant iterations to suffice.

To reach a defined accuracy (by some metric), you can look at the residual from preconditioned conjugate gradient. (Then I’d recompute the Cholesky decomposition every Θ(1) iterations of preconditioned conjugate gradient.)

Comment: Hi David - Thank you for the algorithm idea!  My matrix A is symmetrical, real and all its elements are positive, but it seems it doesn't have to be positive definite; I got the eigenvalues of a few example matrixes and there's always one negative eigenvalue.

Is there a modified version of this that would work?  (Maybe something involving an interative method like MINRES?)

Comment: @AlexI Yeah, the general template is: 1) find a O(n^3)-time matrix decomposition method that lets you solve for one particular matrix in O(n^2) time; 2) use an preconditioned indirect method where the preconditioner is the old matrix. MINRES fits the bill for 2). For 1), I would probably try LU with pivoting, falling back to QR if you have stability issues, but perhaps your MINRES implementation has a preferred format for the preconditioner. If it's not working, then https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is probably the right place to ask followups (not off topic here, but the experts are there).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to incrementally update the inverse of matrix `A`.

To speed up the matrix multiplications, you could use a suitable matrix multiplication algorithm or a library tuned for high-performance computing. The classic matrix multiplication has complexity `O(n³)`. [Strassen](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strassens-matrix-multiplication-algorithm-implementation/)-type algorithms have `O(n^2.8)` and better.

A similiar question without real answer was asked [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/351010-fastest-methods-to-solve-nonlinear-systems-many-times).

Comment: Axel - this is interesting, but I'm not sure my updated matrix can be written (even approximately) as $A + u v^T$.  How about taking a few steps of conjugate gradient?  (with or without restart)

Answer (score 1):

### In general, a solution might not exist for `Ὰ`

Given that `Ax = b` and `A + ε = Ὰ`, the rank of `Ὰ` doesn't necessarily equal the rank of `A`.

If you use the Frobenius norm of `ε` to denote the distance between `A` and `Ὰ`, I'm not sure that a bound exists on the rank distance between `A` and `Ὰ` in terms of the norm of `ε`

For instance **if** a bound did exist and you could say:

`rank(A - Ὰ) < f(‖ε‖) < 1`

Then you would know that a solution exists as long as you choose `ε` so that `f(‖ε‖) < 1`